# Javascript arrays: remove element contained in array inside array

Tags: javascript

Imagine something like:

```
const newItem = ['item 1', 'item 0', 'item 1', 'item 2', 'item 1', 'item 0'];
```

If I want to remove all 'item 1' I can use:

```
for (let i = newItem.length-1; i--;){
    if (newItem[i] === "item 1") newItem.splice(i, 1);
}
```

The question is if I have an array inside another array how can I do?

```
const newItem = [
    ['item 1', 'item 0', 'item 1'],
    ['item 2', 'item 1', 'item 0']
];
```

Thanks!

Comment: `arr = arr.map(subArr => subArr.filter(element => element !== 'item 1'))`

Comment: @Seblor it is always good to use one liner but OP seems to be new in this so I would suggest a detailed way using `for` or `forEach()`

Comment: Sure, but this is why I wrote it as a comment not an answer. Writing the one liner here can be a way to introduce OP to the functional programming side of JS.

Comment: do you want to keep the object reference or is a new array ok? what about empty array after filtering/splicing?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` and `filter`.`map` will return a new array and inside the callback check if the item which is `['item 1', 'item 0', 'item 1']` &
`['item 2', 'item 1', 'item 0']` `includes` `item 1`

```js
const newItem = [
  ['item 1', 'item 0', 'item 1'],
  ['item 2', 'item 1', 'item 0']
];

let k = newItem.map(function(item) {
  return item.filter(elm => elm !== 'item 1')
});

console.log(k)
//newItem is not changed
console.log(newItem)
```

Comment: Is there a reason for `item.includes` ? (Aside from reducing the number of loops)

Comment: INCORRECT, The value of `newItem` is not changed. You actually need to remove value from that array

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal it is changed, since `map` is used. You can even run the snippet to see it work.

Comment: @Seblor check the snippet it dont work. `newItem` is not changed. We expect that array to get changed with no `item1`

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Ah right. You just need to affect the return value from `map` to `newItem`.

Comment: That is the reason we can keep things simple just by loops instead of `map` and `filter` to confuse OP. @Seblor

Comment: map & filter confuse OP? Don’t know about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `map` and `filter`:

```js
const newItem = [
 ['item 1', 'item 0', 'item 1'],
 ['item 2', 'item 1', 'item 0']
];
console.log(newItem.map(a => a.filter(e => e !== 'item 1')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use nested `forEach()` loop:

```js
const newItem = [
  ['item 1', 'item 0', 'item 1'],
  ['item 2', 'item 1', 'item 0']
];
newItem.forEach((innerArray) => {
  innerArray.forEach((innerItem, i) => {
    if (innerItem === "item 1") innerArray.splice(i, 1);
  });
});
console.log(newItem);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering and helping with my question!

Answer (score 1):

If you know which index you want to access, one way to easily access this:

```
var arr = [[1,2,3], [5,6,7]];
console.log(arr[0][1]); // This will print 2, the second element of the first array item.
```

You can also easily iterate the nested array items using nested loop:

```
var arr = [
  ["item1", "item2", "item3"], ["item1", "item2", "item3"]];
arr.forEach(function(arrayItem){
    arrayItem.forEach(function(item, index, array){
         if(item === "item1"){
             array.splice(index, 1); // Removes the matching item from the arrayItem.
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you downvote, kindly provide a reason why so that I can improve my answer or for future reference in case I missed something.